# Оптимизация цикла в 10 000 000 повторов

Tags: c#, массивы

Мой код

```
    public static class Canal
    {
        public static List<byte> A = new List<byte>();
        public static List<byte> R = new List<byte>();
        public static List<byte> G = new List<byte>();
        public static List<byte> B = new List<byte>();
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("Canal_A.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var array = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(array, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            Canal.A.AddRange(array);
        }
        using (var fs = new FileStream("Canal_R.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var array = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(array, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            Canal.R.AddRange(array);
        }
        using (var fs = new FileStream("Canal_G.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var array = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(array, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            Canal.G.AddRange(array);
        }
        using (var fs = new FileStream("Canal_B.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var array = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(array, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            Canal.B.AddRange(array);
        }
    }

    public void F()
    {
        var color = new List<Color>();

        for (int i = 0; i <Canal.A.Count; i++)
        {
            color.Add(Color.FromArgb(Canal.A[i], Color.FromArgb(Canal.R[i], Canal.G[i], Canal.B[i])));
        }
    }
```

У меня в файлах раздельно хранится ARGB каналы картинки. Я считываю все каналы, потом создаю из них цвета, затем из цветов делаю картинку. Все работает. Но когда  я вызываю `F()` то цикл отжерает около 1 Гб оперативки, в зависимости от размера картинки, и при этом память не освобождается после отработки функции. Как результат каждый вызов функции + 1 Гб занятой оперативы(( Как это можно оптимизировать? Я так понял что память отжерает из за того что цикл больше 10 мил раз отрабатует, но почему тогда после отработки память остается забитой?

Вот полная функция, больше программа не делает ничего.

```
    public static void Decoder(string fileName)
    {
        var color = new List<Color>();

        Load();

        for (int i = 0; i < Canal.A.Count; i++)
        {
            color.Add(Color.FromArgb(Canal.A[i], Color.FromArgb(Canal.R[i], Canal.G[i], Canal.B[i])));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(".....");

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(fileName))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(j, i, color[counter]);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            bmp.Save($"_{fileName}");
        }
        color.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("FINISH");
    }
```

Comment: А вы где-то закрываете открытые файлы?)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, вообще using выполняет эту функцию. У меня подозрение, что автор выложил далеко не весь код и проблема вполне может быть в другом коде (а часто именно так и бывает, я не первый год на вопросы отвечаю на разных форумах). Где здесь в коде показан полный цикл работы программы, из которого бы было видно куда деваются ранее прочитанный данные.

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev да `using` вызывает `fs.Close();` и `fs.Dispose();`, да и память отжерает именно когда отрабатывает цикл в `F()` а он работает уже со списками, а не файлами.

Comment: такое чувство что `var color = new List<Color>();` создает постоянно новые экземпляры, а старые `GC` не удаляет

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц возможно, но я делал `color.Clear()` после цикла - и не помогло.

Comment: а в этом коде точно есть проблема???...не вижу смысла с функции `F()`

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц добавил полную функцию

Comment: А программа бесконечно отъедает оперативку и не освобождает её? То есть в итоге она падает? Просто пока ОС не нужны ресурсы, оперативка вполне может отъедаться.

Comment: @CasperSC  после вызова `Decoder()` отжерает гиг оперативы, если вызвать повторно то уже два гига, но повторные вызовы память за собой очищают. А если продублировать цикл что заполняет лист цветов несколько раз, отжирает всю оперативу и все виснет так что прогу сложно закрыть

Comment: @Владислав А с чем связано использование List в классе Canal и color = new List ? Мне кажется обычный массив было бы гораздо проще, да и проблем с утечкой памяти не было бы.

Comment: Ну так сделай просто несколько снапшотов памяти и посмотри на что сожралась

Comment: может дело в `Canal.A.AddRange(array);` и тому подобное....похоже на то что оно растет

Comment: @Геннадий П с тем, что я заранее не занаю длину массива в классе, а вот color заменил массивам и пямять в почти 2 раза меньше отнимать стало

Comment: Я бы привел код который не съедал бы даже 1 МБ ОЗУ, но увы, у меня нет ни фреймворка под рукой, ни редакторов =)

Comment: @Владислав Как это не знаете? Вы же считываете определенные данные из файла.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, статические классы сборщик мусора не забирает, т.к. фактически они не являются объектами и не потребляют память. **НО** статические поля статического класса - уже являются объектами и хранятся в памяти и не будут собраны GC, потому что будут доступны в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения. В вашем случае, можно попытаться принудительно присвоить значение `null` полям класса `Canal`: (A,R,G,B), чтобы они стали доступны для GC.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в Decoder вызывается функция Load, заполняющая листы каналов, но при этом ни где не происходит очистка каналов => память закономерно будет утекать, т.к. листы каналов будут постоянно увеличиваться.

Добавьте предварительную очистку каналов, например так:

```
...
using (var fs = new FileStream("Canal_A.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    Canal.A.Clear();
    var array = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(array, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    Canal.A.AddRange(array);
}
...
```

для каждого соответственно. При каждой следующей загрузке данных, предыдущие будут гарантировано выгружены и, позже, съедены GC. Если скорость реакции GC будет маловата, а данных очень много, то можно его принудительного пнуть с помощью `GC.Collect()`. Только не нужно трогать GC при малом объеме данных, это ни чего не даст кроме ухудшения производительности.

---

Еще можно модифицировать ваш класс с каналами

```
public static class Canal
{
    public static byte[] A;
    public static byte[] R;
    public static byte[] G;
    public static byte[] B;
}
```

Тогда заполнение делать так:

```
public static void Load()
{
    Canal.A = File.ReadAllBytes("Canal_A.txt");
    Canal.R = File.ReadAllBytes("Canal_R.txt");
    Canal.G = File.ReadAllBytes("Canal_G.txt");
    Canal.B = File.ReadAllBytes("Canal_B.txt");
}
```

Тут очистка не требуется, т.к. мы каждый раз создаем канал заново. Ручную работу с потоком заменил на готовое решение фреймворка, раз уж вы вычитываете файлы целиком. Ручная работа с потоком была бы полезна при поточной обработке файлов без полной загрузки их в память, а в вашем варианте просто еще одно место возможной ошибки.

Comment: Вы в классе вроде бы определили `public static byte A;` а инициализируете `Canal.A = new byte[(int)fs.Length];`

Comment: @ヒミコ очепятка, спасибо

Comment: Касты к int лишние.

Comment: @Qwertiy только один лишний, Read на вход int хочет а длина потока long, перегрузки такой нет. Можно правда вообще заменить `File.ReadAllBytes` и не страдать на тему `using` и параметров `Read`, все равно автор целиком вычитывает файлы